# Solr and postgresql integration

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, solr

I want to add the search engine Solr to my Java application. I want to index some information in Solr, but not everything, because my database is very specific.

I don't want to explain everything because is complex, so I'll use a simple example.

Let's say I have a table named *T*, with two columns *col1* and *col2*:

```
 col1             | col2
------------------|----------
 some text...     |  123
 another text...  |  41
 bla bla...       |  124
```

I want to index only the *col1* column in the Solr engine. I don't want to index *col2* column in Solr - I know it's possible, but I don't want to do this.

In the search on my application I want to filter information from both columns. For example I need to get rows with *"Lorem ipsum dolorem"* in *col1*, and with values in range [5, 163] in *col2*.

How can I do this?

I use PostgreSQL and Hibernate, but perhaps I will change it to MongoDB.

Answer (score 11):

First, in your example, if you don't want to index *col2* but you do want to search with filters specific to *col2*, do you plan to hand code some filter on top of the results? Because to filter something, it would have to be part of the index... right?

I found a blog post about hooking up [Solr to mysql via a JDBC handler jar](http://blog.comperiosearch.com/blog/2014/08/28/indexing-database-using-solr/), and I found an example of the specific syntax for the [PostgreSQL JDBC jar](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandlerFaq#Running_Out_of_Memory_with_Postgresql).

Putting the two together I would speculate that the steps would be (adjust as needed, because likely you've got something that partially works):

1. In `solrconfig.xml` put:

   > ```
   > <lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-\d.*\.jar" />
   >
   > <requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
   > <lst name="defaults">
   > <str name="config">db-data-config.xml</str>
   > </lst>
   > </requestHandler>
   > ```
2. Add this to your `schema.xml`:

   > ```
   > <dynamicField name="*_name" type="text_general" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   > ```
3. Add a `db-data-config.xml` similar to the linked blog post but with something like (I've removed the limit, not sure if postgreSQL has a different limit syntax or not):

   > ```
   > <dataConfig>
   >   <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
   >             driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
   >             url="jdbc:postgresql://host/db"
   >             user="user"
   >             password="password" /> 
   >   <document>
   >     <entity name="T" query="select col1 as 'col1' from T;" />
   >   </document>
   > </dataConfig>
   > ```

Also look at [the other follow on post](http://blog.comperiosearch.com/blog/2015/04/14/solr-indexing-index-sql-databases-made-easier-part-2/) for details on facets, which might help you accomplish some of the filtering you were hoping to do.